# Redirect page to different URLs based on input form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to redirect my users on different URLs based on the text they enter in input and I've seen this question [Need to redirect form to multiple URLs based on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769132/need-to-redirect-form-to-multiple-urls-based-on-input)

And I've tried the same thing but I don't know why this is not working for me please find my code below, whenever I click on the 'GO' button nothing happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urlMapping = {
    "STRING1" : "https://google.com/",
    "STRING2" : "https://stackoverflow.com/",
    "STRING3" : "https://twitter.com/home"
}

$("#submit-form").click(function(){
    var input = $("input").val().trim().toUpperCase();
    if (urlMapping.hasOwnProperty(input)){
        window.location = urlMapping[input];
    }
    else {
        //if url not found, redirect to default url
        window.location = "./default.html";
    }
});

</script>

<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text">
         <button id="submit-form" type="button">Go</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like a document ready issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Your script is above the html.  At the point in time the script runs, the form does not exist yet

Comment: @Taplar Hi, can you show me how can I implement this on my code, I'm really sorry but I'm kinda new to this and clearly I'm doing something wrong, and it's still not working, yes I'm using .html

Comment: Please read the duplicate.  The gist is browsers parse html documents from the top down.  So if you have a `<script>` defined above other tags, and the script is trying to do things with those other tags, it will not work because they do not exist yet.  The duplicate covers different ways to address this, one of which is to simply put your script after the elements that it needs to manipulate.

Comment: @Taplar I've tried before putting my script after the elements too and it still didn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6h7ucv40/  works fine

Comment: @Taplar ok so apparently I had to put it after the jquery.min.js too and it worked, before I was just putting it after the element. Thank you so much it's solved